# Msys terminal run command permantly

Tags: command-line, msys2, msys

I want to run this command:

```
chcp.com 1253
```

permantly in msys2 terminal.

I don't want to write this command every time a msys2 mingw 64 terminal is open.

```
Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MINGW64 ~
$ cd /c/Users/Χρήστος\ Παππάς/Desktop/

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MINGW64 /c/Users/Χρήστος Παππάς/Desktop
$ python ελληνικά.py
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MINGW64 /c/Users/Χρήστος Παππάς/Desktop
$ chcp.com 1253
Active code page: 1253

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MINGW64 /c/Users/Χρήστος Παππάς/Desktop
$ python ελληνικά.py
Εληννικά

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MINGW64 /c/Users/Χρήστος Παππάς/Desktop
$
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas

Comment: [`.bashrc`](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file)?

Comment: That's it. Check my answer please for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `vim ~/.bashsrc`
2. Press I key (goes from read mode to insert mode for edit the file)
3. Move at the bottom of the file and type `chcp.com 1253`
4. Then press Esc, w key, q key, ! key and press Enter

That's it.
Every time I open the msys console i see something like:

```
Active code page: 1253

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MSYS /c/Users/Χρήστος Παππάς/Documents/projects/Papinhio player
```

Comment: Pro tip: use `nano` instead of `vim` for a commad-line editor that doesnt't require memorizing a crapton of hotkeys.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Maybe you are right.
We used vi(m) in our university lab. :)